# Isomorphism, Model-Theorie, "beginning"

Tags: model-theory

> Let $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}=(N, <_{\mathcal{N}^{\ast}},...)$ be a model of $Q$ (the Robinson arithmetic).
>
> Show, that it exists a "beginning" (definition below) of $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N}, <, +,\cdot, E, 0, 1)$ ($E$ notes the exponatiation)

"beginning": A "beginning" is a model of the form $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}_{|X}$, where $X=N$ or it exists a $x\in N$ with $X=\{y\in N: y<_{\mathcal{N}^{\ast}} x\}$

I gave our definition of $Q$ here: [Peano Arithmetic, proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822391/peano-arithmetic-proof/1822441#1822441) (Axioms 1-9)

Hello,

I have a question to this task.
I have to show, that $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}\cong\mathcal{N}$ hence the structures are isomorphic.

Therefore I have to give an isomorphism $\pi:N\to\mathbb{N}$ with certain properties.

But I am unsure, if there is not an easier way to solve this. $\mathcal{N}$ contains many relationsyombols, functions and constants. So it could get a bit hairy.
Also I dont know if $\mathcal{N}^{\ast}$ contains the same functions, relationsymbols and contains, since only $<_{\mathcal{N}^{\ast}}$ is explicit mentioned. But I think so.

Anyways. I have to show that it exists a beginning, such that it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$. So $X$ has to be infinite, otherwise I can not give a bijection.

Do you have a tip on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you've correctly quoted the definition of "beginning"? With this definition, what you're trying to prove is not generally true.

Comment: I checked it, and I am pretty sure I translated and quoted it correctly. Unfortunatly my professor is known to be a little bit "sloppy" from time to time. Do you know what has to be changed to make the definition "work", or do you know a similar definition of "beginning"?

Comment: Otherwise, do you have a counterexample?

Comment: In any nonstandard model of Peano Arithmetic (which is, in particular a model of Robinson's Q) $<$ is a linear ordering, and there is no smallest nonstandard element. For the standard part of such a model to be a beginning, in the sense of your definition, it would have to be the set of strict predecessors of some $x$, and that $x$ would have to be the smallest nonstandard element.  To make the desired result correct, a "beginning" of a model of Q should be defined as a subset $X$ of the model such that, if $a<b$ in the model and if $b\in X$, then also $a\in X$.  I.e., $X$ is closed downward.

Comment: The definition got corrected today. It is how you said. But even with the new definition, what do I have to show here?

Comment: I suggest proceeding as follows for the proof. First, given any model $A$ of $Q$, define a function $h$ from the natural numbers into (the underlying set of) $A$ in such a way that it respects 0 and the successor operation. There is a unique such $h$. Then, using the axioms of $Q$, show that $h$ is one-to-one and also respects $+,\times$, and $<$. Finally, again using axioms of $Q$, show that the image of $h$ is a beginning of $A$.